# Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-authentication

I have searched for a solution to this problem everywhere, but could not find a satisfying answer.

I am trying to set up a sign-in page on my already built application by using firebase, but I came across with the error in the title in the first phase of set up. Even though I went through all steps on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin), I still got the error as shown below:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

I also downloaded all the necessary SDK tools as explained in the firebase instructions, but still cannot locate any folder under the name */gms* (looks like it was not downloaded).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You need to setup the Google Repository in the SDK Manager

Comment: Also, `3.1.0` is the latest version. https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: This was not enough for set up?
http://imgur.com/a/olkst

Comment: Looks good, but again, `3.1.0` is the latest

Comment: All packages are up to date within my project, I don't get how to upgrade to 3.1.0 and this url doesn't focus on that either.

Answer (score 9):

**Step 0**
Instead of 3.0.0, make it 3.1.0

change this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`

**Step 1**
To solve this problem, go to 
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\google\gms\google-services\3.1.0"

If you do not find any folder, create it.

**Step 2**
Download two files,

*google-services-3.1.0.jar*
(http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.0/google-services-3.1.0.jar)

*google-services-3.1.0.pom*
(https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/gms/google-services/3.1.0/google-services-3.1.0.pom)
,paste them into the folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked here. Life-saver

Answer (score 3):

Modify your project build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()  // helps me to resolve this issue
    }

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0"
    }
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

[The third step add firebase to your app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ18m.png)

Do you just add this line: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
to your app build.gradle,not project build.gradle?

Comment: Please don't answer question with a question.

Comment: No,i think that maybe the reason why the question appear,but i am not sure.I appear the problem because of that.

Comment: Although it's a poorly worded answer, adding 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'' to my project build.gradle resolved the "Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0" for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I changed the name of google-services.json file to googleservices.json. This was causing an error.
The error was solved when I deleted all the earlier copies of the json file, downloaded the file again, and followed the remaining procedure as it is.

Comment: i used 3.1.0 btw

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today. I made mistake to write this line

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

on module level build.gradle, not on project level build.gradle. after I move that line to project level build.gradle, the error fixed.